# Is there any working Cordova Push Notification?

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification, notifications, cordova-plugins

Is there any working Cordova Push Notification plugin?
This one has been disabled:

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push
```

Thank you

Trying this now:

```
https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this now :

```
https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Okay so did it work?

Comment: i'm getting "FCMPlugin is not defined" error.
I'm going to try @Muhammad Faizan Uddin solution using cordovaPushV5

Comment: @GauravOjha the plugin works :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it in my project as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a paid solution - Pushwoosh should also help.

There is a free version too for unlimited push notifications. This could be integrated with cordova, if you want

Link: https://www.pushwoosh.com/

Documentation for integration: http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap

Comment: thanks @HawkEye, i'll consider it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one, an old one but it simply works: https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-push-notifications